# Maintaining aspect ratio based on width and height with CSS only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The goal is to define an aspect ratio (f.E. 4:3) for a DIV and all children of it, that have the styles WIDTH:100% and HEIGHT:100%.

This works fine, as long as I set the parent

```
WIDTH:100%
```

and then add to the first child a

```
PADDING-BOTTOM: 75%; // (3/4)*100
```

But if I resize my window to full screen on a 1080p monitor, the inner box will (sadly) *correctly* grow to be 100% in width and to 75% of the width, in height. Thus a 1920pixel wide div will grow to 1920x1440. On a 1080p screen this means, that I will have scrollbars to see the complete content of the div.

**I'd prefer the inner box to only be (window.innerHeight / 3) * 4 wide and have a black bar on the left (and/or) right.**

So I assumed that setting the height on the parent and then defining a padding-right on the child would have the same effect, but would give me the black bars on the right of the screen and not on the bottom.

But this does **not** work if you set the parent

```
HEIGHT:100%
```

and then add a

```
PADDING-RIGHT: 33% // ((4/3)-1)*100
```

to the children because **the paddings are based on the containing elements width**.

Now in a perfect world, I'd like to have my div, no matter what the height and width of the parent are, to be exactly 4:3, with black bars around it if neccessary , without ever being bigger in any dimension than the parent and thus creating scroll bars.

Is this possible with purely CSS? Or will I have to use JavaScript?

**Edit**:

with

```
<div style="width:133vmin;height:100vmin;margin-left:-66vmin;left:50%;background: #f00; overflow:hidden;">
```

I'm able to define a div that has 4:3 aspect ratio and has blackbars on the left and right, **but** if the height is not enough, it will not grow in size. Now I'd need to somehow combine both solutions...

Comment: can you use max-height to solve it?

Comment: Hi Medda86, thanks for this idea. Initially I couldn't imagine how this could help me, but a restriction on the maximum width to be not more than 4/3 of the height worked well. Thx for the nudge in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a solution, but sadly it doesn't work with the latest stable Chrome, there is a bug filed: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94158

**However it does work on Firefox 25.0 and Chrome Canary 36.0.1922.0**

```
<html>
<style>

body {
    margin:0;
    background: #000;
}

#block1 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: calc(100vh * 1.33333); // (4 / 3)
}
#block1:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin-top: 75%; // (3 / 4) * 100
}
#block2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: red;
}

</style>
<body>
<div id="block1"><div id="block2"></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also works on Chrome Mobile Beta 34.0.1847.99 but not on Chrome Mobile 33

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS should look like:

```
#block1{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;        /* desired width */
}
#block1:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 75%;   /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}
#block2{
    position:  absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

That should do it. Works cross browser back to IE8.

Comes form this great article: http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html